# HOW TO update existing jsonb array attribute for a single item in the array

Tags: json, postgresql

```
'{"user_profile":[
       {
        "profile_name":"customer",
        "user_status":"NEW","user_state":"pending",
         "s3url":["file1","abc/1/clients/51/clients/acmepm1/"],
         "groups":["g1","g2"]
         },
       {
        "profile_name":"admin staff",
        "user_status":"NEW","user_state":"admin upload",
         "s3url":"abc/"
         }
]}'
```

I would like to change "groups":["g1","g2"] to "groups":["group1","group2"] for "profile_name":"customer"

I could get this far

```
update users set user_details=(select elem -'groups'||'{"groups":["a","b"]}' from users u 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(user_details->'user_profile') elem --with ordinality arr(user_details,index) 
where elem->>'profile_name'='customer' )
```

But this is not correct. As this removes the "admin staff" profile completely, and also the Array "Customer_profile" is gone.
the jsonb becomes

```
{"s3url": ["file1", "abc/1/clients/51/clients/acmepm1/"], "groups": ["a", "b"], "user_state": "pending", "user_status": "NEW", "profile_name": "customer"}
```

How do I achieve the update I am looking for?

Comment: Do you know the index of the `"profile_name":"customer"` object in the array?

Comment: I am not sure I know how to answer that question. It's array[0] and one of the name-value  pair. But I do understand enough to answer your question what is the index of profile_name:customer

Comment: Yes. If you knew the index, you could use `jsonb_set(user_details, '{user_profile, 0, groups}' , '…')`. If you don't, and need to use a `WHERE` clause, you'll need to aggregate the array elements back into an array.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work... I tried something like this to update the 2 value of the groups array and it worked.   update users 
set user_details=jsonb_set(user_details,'{user_profile,0,groups,2}','"Newattvalue"');

Answer (score 0):

To replace the array in the `jsonb` value you show, use

```
SELECT jsonb_set(
          '{"user_profile":
              [
                 {"profile_name":"customer",
                  "user_status":"NEW",
                  "user_state":"pending",
                  "s3url":
                     ["file1","abc/1/clients/51/clients/acmepm1/"],
                  "groups":
                     ["g1","g2"]
                 },
                 {"profile_name":"admin staff",
                  "user_status":"NEW",
                  "user_state":"admin upload",
                  "s3url":"abc/"
                 }
              ]
           }'::jsonb,
           '{user_profile,0,groups}',
           ["group1","group2"]
        );
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.13.1.1.1) for details about `jsonb_set`. The first array element is referenced as "0".